# Is it possible to install windows app on linux or mac OS?

Tags: c#, operating-system

I have created a windows forms app which will have some configurations and based on that app will collect files from particular folder and transfer it to FTP.

A setup installable file is created for this app. Is it possible to this app to install on linux or mac OS?

Answer (score 0):

.NET apps are platform dependent and can only be run on Windows platform and that's why .NET is not preferred if you want to run your app on multiple platforms.

That being said, Microsoft came up with .NET Core which is platform independent and hence any Forms App you create on .NET Core will run on Linux as well.

The only way I can think of, if you want to run pure .NET apps, is to have VM installed on your host(Linux or Mac) which has Windows installed as Guest.